# How can I specify the languages that apt-get uses?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, environment-variables, .profile

At some point in my installation, I must've selected several languages as default. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I got output similar to the following.

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_CA
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_AU
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
```

I want to make apt-get only search for `en_AU`, `en_GB` and `en`. i.e. I want to remove `en_NZ` and `en_CA`.
When I run `locale`, I indeed get the output `LANGUAGE=en_AU:en_NZ:en_GB:en_CA:en`.
I modified my `~/.profile` to change

```
export LANGUAGE="en_AU:en_NZ:en_GB:en_CA:en"
```

to

```
export LANGUAGE="en_AU:en_GB:en"
```

then rebooted. Now, locale shows only the three languages as expected, but when I run `sudo apt-get update`, I still see `en_CA` being searched for. Oddly enough, I get the following output too.

```
$ apt-config dump | grep Lang
Acquire::Languages "";
Acquire::Languages:: "en_AU";
Acquire::Languages:: "en";
Acquire::Languages:: "en_GB";
Acquire::Languages:: "none";
Acquire::Languages:: "en_CA";
```

so it seems that apt-get is looking elsewhere for the `en_CA` entry. The problem is that I cannot find where this could be. I don't quite understand the man page of `apt-config`, but `$APT_CONFIG` is empty, `/etc/apt/` doesn't contain a file named `apt.conf`, nor do I get anything recursively grepping this directory for `en_CA`. So my question is… how can I make apt-get forget about `en_CA`?

Comment: You wrote "I modified my ~/.profile" but *my* .profile has this comment at the beginning: "This file is not read by bash(1), if `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists." So maybe you want to check for that?

Comment: Neither of those two exist for me. Also, since the output of `locale` changed after I modified `~/.profile`, I assume that bash is reading it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have leftover files in /var/lib/apt/lists/ from when you had changed the locales. Apt.conf is not used anymore, but Apt is building the config database from that list of files (among other things). If you look in the dir, you will see files with "translation" and "en_CA" in the name. The Ign messages are simply Apt telling you that the files are not needed and are being ignored. Harmless, but very annoying.

You could remove the orphaned files safely by hand, but it's much easier to remove all of the lists and rebuild them.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Excellent! Rebuilding that directory fixed it for me. I was trying to reduce the time it took to update, since I figured apt-get was looking for unnecessary files, but perhaps that's not the case. All the en_NZ entries did say Ign, but there were two en_CA entries with Hit. Is that saying that these repository *are* being searched?